# Unhandled Runtime Error deploying a Next-Strapi web app on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, next.js, strapi

I'm deploying a web app made with Next y Strapi on Heroku. It shows me this error message: **Unhandled Runtime Error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url')**

It can't show images deployed on Heroku.

```
function Game(props){
  const { game } = props;
  return (
    <Grid.Column className='list-games__game'>
      <Link href={`/${game.url}`}>
        <a>
          <div className='list-games__game-poster'>
            <p>{game.title}</p>
            <Image 
              src={game.poster.url} 
              alt={game.title}/>
            <div className="list-games__game-poster-info">
              {game.discount ? (
                <span className="discount">-{game.discount}%</span>
              ) : (
                <span />
              )}
              <span className="price">{game.price}€</span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <h2>{game.title}</h2>
        </a>
      </Link>
    </Grid.Column>
  )
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the data for the `game` prop? Please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

your game props is undefined, I suggest checking it by adding a question mark before the dot and it will prevent runtime errors in the production enviroment.

```
  <Grid.Column className='list-games__game'>
  <Link href={`/${game?.url}`}>
    <a>
      <div className='list-games__game-poster'>
        <p>{game?.title}</p>
        <Image 
          src={game.poster.url} 
          alt={game?.title}/>
        <div className="list-games__game-poster-info">
          {game?.discount ? (
            <span className="discount">-{game?.discount}%</span>
          ) : (
            <span />
          )}
          <span className="price">{game?.price}€</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <h2>{game?.title}</h2>
    </a>
  </Link>
</Grid.Column>
```